# Elegant way of counting how many times patterns from a file occur in another file

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, grep, join

Imagine that we have two for example files. The first file is filled with unique names of employees created by combining the first two characters of the first name and the last 2 characters of the last name. `Example : Peter Smith - Peht`

First file contains :

```
Peht
Mawo
Stso
Makr
Bavo
```

The second file contains recordings about them when they logged into the system. ( Obviously there are also employees that are not listed in `file1`. )

The second file:

```
Mawo 21.4.2016 17:49
Peht 21.4.2016 17:58
Mawo 22.4.2016 7:58
Wato 22.4.2016 7:59
Stso 22.4.2016 8:02
Bavo 22.4.2016 8:15
Bane 22.4.2016 9:01
Bavo 23.4.2016 9:12
Mawo 23.4.2016 9:24
Dalo 23.4.2016 9:54
Peht 23.4.2016 9:58
Grma 24.4.2016 10:00
```

> I need to find out how many times employes from file1 connected to
>   the system ( `file2` ).

What is the best way of doing that? The only solution which came to my mind is to make some 2 loops and for each name from `file1` loop the whole `file2` then `grep` names, ask if the names match if yes then `count++`. Could anyone give me some elegant solution for this problem using for example `awk` if it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simple like:

```
mapfile -t names < file1
for name in "${names[@]}"
do
  echo "${name}" $(grep -c "^$name " file2)
done
```

Will provide output like:

```
Peht 2
Mawo 3
Stso 1
Makr 0
Bavo 2
```

The grep string says to anchor the username at the beginning (^) of the line, and enforce a trailing space after the line.

Answer (score 2):

test.awk:

```
FNR == NR{ 
  names[$1]
  next
}   
($1 in names){
  ulog[$1]++
}   
END{
  for(name in ulog){
    print name ":" ulog[name]
  }   
}
```

and run it as
`awk -f test.awk user.list user.log`

FNR==NR # does the file record number == the record number, if it does then we are still in the first file

next # as we are still in the first file, skip the rest and pull in the next line

The rest should be self explanatory

or as a one-liner

`awk 'FNR == NR{ names[$1]; next } ($1 in names){ ulog[$1]++ } END{ for(name in ulog){ print name ":" ulog[name] } }' user.list user.log`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way with `join`/`sort`/`uniq`:

```
join  -1 1 -2 2 -a1 -e "0" -o 1.1 2.1 <(sort file1) \
<(cut -d' ' -f1 file2 | sort | uniq -c)
```

Basically, it joins the names in `file1` with the `uniq`ue names and counts from `file2` using `0` for the missing fields in `file2`.

---

With `awk` I would run:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1]++;next}
{if ($1 in s) {print $1, s[$1]}
else {print $1, 0}}' file2 file1
```

This reads `file2` first, counts how many times each name occurs then reads `file1` and for each name it prints the count from `file2` (if a name is not in `file2` it prints 0).